# minikube image load only if local image has changed

Tags: minikube

It takes a while to run `minikube image load` to load my locally built image- even if I have not rebuilt the image.

I can't find any args that support having minikube compare hashes first and only upload if they are different.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no built-in args that compare hashes in minikube to upload the images if they are different.  You can use [–overwrite](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/image/#minikube-image-load) flag to the minikube image load command to overwrite the image even if the same image : tag name exists(default true).

Please review the [github links](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/13949) for more information on [uploading the images](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/11322) and [overwrite flag](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/pull/11366).

**EDIT:**

If you have a container currently using the image running in minikube, image load does not overwrite the existing image. If you delete the deployment and stop the container the image load overwrites. Due to running deployment, image load will take time to load the image to minikube. Check this [link](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/13511) for more information.

The other way is you can build the image inside the minikube using the following command. In this way the image is not required to load.

```
$ minikube image build -t localhost:5000/my-image
```

For more detailed information refer to the [minikube image](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/image/#minikube-image-build) page

Comment: I thought it overwrote it by default. Thats confusing are you sure thats not default behavior? It takes the same amount of time to upload if the image changed or not which should mean its overwriting it.

Comment: @red888, Overwriting the image is not by default. Please check my edited answer and let me know whether it helped you.